# SSIS - Database objects versus SQL code inside SSIS objects

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am reviewing a SSIS project and I am finding a lot of SQL code (Updates, selects, etc.), some of them quite complex, "hidden" inside SSIS objects . I was thinking in transfer this SQL to the database using views, sps and/or other objects in order to improve the readability, reusability and organization.

In you opinion what is the best practice that should be followed? Keep all the logic in the SSIS or transfer the logic to the database calling, for example, stored procedures or views? Is there any inconvenience?

Answer (score 1):

One the one hand, when reversing engineering and understanding a package, it can get annoying to have to switch to the database tool all the time to work out what some code is doing. It can also be a bit complicated to have to deploy the right database object with the right SSIS package.

On the other hand, embedding code in the database is a good way to reuse code and importantly be able to fix and maintain data flow without having to open up a package (and possibly have it choke when metadata has changed etc.)

Personally one thing that annoys me is over-complicated packages containing unions, joins, lookups etc which could be much more simply written as a single SQL query. Often packages are built that way because the author doesn't know any better, and my opinion is that an ETL author should know how to write and use SQL.

Lastly, some of the SSIS components just aren't good enough, i.e. the row by row update component and the lookup component that for some reason has to do row by row lookups if your lookup key uses a range (i.e date range for an SCD)

So I don't have any best practices for you, just observations. The best practice really is be consistent and build ETL that is suited to the maintenance team skills.

Comment: I came here to write exactly the same thing. I would add the my many many years of experience has lead me to believe that less terse and less opaque code leads to easier (thus cheaper) maintenance - and SSIS especially . The only time I now deviate is where the SQL concerned added stress to the underlying data source that is unwanted. In such cases I'd even go so far as to say its sometimes better to add a transformation database/views on another server as opposed to some hidden code in an SSIS package.

Comment: :) it's a relief to know that I'm not the only 'Luddite' that thinks that you should avoid creating a tangle of dataflows inside a convoluted SSIS package... and also maintenance is such vital aspect of development.

Comment: Creating maintenance ease is the one thing that should be at the top of all architecting lists as this is usually the most costly over time.

Comment: Unfortunately whoever is footing the budget for the development effort never sees it that way :). I write this as I continue my daily struggle  with technical debt.

Comment: First of all, thank you for all your answers. 

Regarding the topic, I also prefer to use SQL instead of some transformations, specially for performance issues. We are already following this path but my concern was the code reusability and organization. I'm seeing I was thinking correctly.

Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from ElectricLlama is very nice and as an ETL developer with a heavy preference for SQL I can definitly get with his way of thinking. I do have 1 very practical addition that can help.

Practically every component that takes SQL command can be set up to use a script as a file. This makes it possible to sort, organize and review the SQL code outside of the package. When adding some context to the top of the script in a comment this really helps.

This way any cowboy behavior is discouraged and brought to the front if it does happen.